# Добавление записи из Access в Delphi DBGRID

Tags: access, база-данных, delphi

Здравствуйте.

Запускаю форму в Delphi. В Access дабавляю запись. Добавленная запись не выводится в DBGRID.

В форме установил кнопку "вывести весь список":

```
procedure TForm1.sBitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQuery1.Filtered:=false;
ADOQuery1.Filter:=('select * from Ученик');
end;
```

Даже если нажимаешь на кнопку, добавленная запись в Access не добавляется в DBGRID.

Чтобы запись добавилась, нужно закрыть и снова запустить форму. Это не удобно.

Как сделать, чтобы запись в Access добавилась в Delphi без обратного запускания?

Answer (score 2):

Запись присутствует, просто нужно переоткрыть `ADOQuery1`. Попробуй расположить под кнопкой этот код :

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.Open;
```